# How to tell Cloudflare to cache your homepage (without file extension)

Tags: cloudflare

Cloudflare caches files with extension `html` for static content. But when visiting the root of a website, eg http://foo.com there is no extension specified, thus this page is not cached as static html. How can I tell Cloudflare to cache the homepage without an extension?

Obviously I could use Apache's htaccess to force traffic from `http://foo.com` to `http://foo.com/index.html` but that means my server will be hit to execute this redirect, and that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: You can of course let [CloudFlare do the redirect](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-) if that is your only concern

Answer (score 0):

You simply use the explicit url as the page rule. Such as `http://foo.com/`.

Comment: But then everything will be cached, including all pages that fall under http://foo.com/blaba/ etc.

Comment: @bart that is incorrect. Only a wildcard rule would do that, such as foo.com/*

Comment: Also @bart - cloiudflare does not cache pages as static content. Even HTML. Unless you explicitly do so with a page rule. This is because any file extension can be driven through a pre processor on the server depending on the configuration.

Comment: Fair enough, but question remains, will a page rule at root level be applied to all subfolders?

Comment: If you use the wildcard character, yes: foo.com/*